# Link paypal account to web service

Tags: php, yii, paypal

There is a system with multiple business accounts and there are system users. Business accounts should be able to link their paypal accounts to the system. Users who buy goods in the system from different business accounts have to pay the bill and the amount of money should transfer to business account accordingly to goods that had been purchased.
Any ideas with implementing this stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably consider [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/). You can be the "caller" of the API and still have it make payments based on an email address supplied without needing to call the API for them.